# Shuffling ObservableList fires incorrect change notification

Tags: java, javafx

Method `FXCollections.shuffle()` fires only `wasRemoved` change notification. As we may know, shuffling isn't only about removing, but removing and adding.

In [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#shuffle(javafx.collections.ObservableList)) we can see:

> Shuffles all elements in the observable list. Fires only **one** change notification on the list.

If I'm not mistaken, a single change can contain both `wasAdded` and `wasRemoved`. What a shame `wasPermutated` isn't being fired with the default `ObservableList` FX api (or is it?).

Code to test it out:

```
public class SimpleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<Integer> integers = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        integers.addListener(initListener());
        FXCollections.shuffle(integers);
    }

    private static ListChangeListener<Integer> initListener() {
        return change -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasPermutated()) {
                    System.out.println("wasPermutated");
                } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    System.out.println("wasRemoved");
                } else if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println("wasAdded");
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: it's probably firing (didn't check, though) a single subchange with both wasAdded and wasRemoved true - your logic catches only one

Comment: btw: when digging into list/Change notification it's a _must_ to read the api doc and follow it to the letter (which you didn't :) - it's fairly complete, though rather dense. Looking into core implementations helps a lot to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

Your code assumes that `wasAdded()` and `wasRemoved()` are mutually exclusive, whether you intended that or not. That assumption is wrong. If one or more contiguous elements are *replaced* then both those methods will return `true`.

Keep in mind there's a difference between a `Change` object and a "change". A single `Change` instance can carry multiple changes. When the documentation says:

> Fires only one change notification on the list.

It is not saying only one `Change` object will be sent to the `ListChangeListener`. What it's saying is that the `Change` object will only carry one change. In other words, the `Change#next()` method will only return `true` for the first invocation and thus your `while` loop will only loop once.

---

## Solution

You need to rewrite your code with the knowledge that both `wasAdded()` and `wasRemoved()` can both be `true`. For instance, here's a listener that checks for all types of changes:

```java
private static ListChangeListener<Integer> initListener() {
  return change -> {
    while (change.next()) {
      if (change.wasPermutated()) {
        System.out.println("wasPermutated");
      } else if (change.wasUpdated()) {
        System.out.println("wasUpdated");
      } else if (change.wasReplaced()) {
        System.out.println("wasReplaced");
      } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
        System.out.println("wasRemoved");
      } else { // only other change type is "added"
        System.out.println("wasAdded");
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The above uses `wasReplaced()` which is the same as `wasAdded() && wasRemoved()`. Note that a check for `wasReplaced()` must happen before either `wasRemoved()` or `wasAdded()` if you use an if-else-if structure. Otherwise the above will suffer the same problem your code has.

If you insert the above into your code and run it you'll see the following output:

```
wasReplaced
```

[The documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) of `ListChangeListener.Change` gives a more general explanation (and example) of how to implement a `ListChangeListener`.

Note the example in the documentation does not check for `wasReplaced()` specifically. Instead, it processes both removed *and* added elements in a final `else` block (after `wasPermutated()` and `wasUpdated()` return `false`). This is possible because `getRemoved()` and `getAddedSubList()` will return empty lists if no element was removed or added, respectively. And it's typically the same effect if you process any removed elements and then any added elements as it is if you specially handle replacements. Depending on your use case, however, it may be beneficial to specially handle replacements.

---

## Why not Permutation?

The way they've implemented the `shuffle` method is:

> ```java
> public static void shuffle(ObservableList list, Random rnd) {
>     Object newContent[] = list.toArray();
>
>     for (int i = list.size(); i > 1; i--) {
>         swap(newContent, i - 1, rnd.nextInt(i));
>     }
>
>     list.setAll(newContent); 
> }
> ```

<sup>*Source: [javafx.collections.FXCollections](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/f4c348fe603ee88d76d7f9be776495d8439c15b1/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/javafx/collections/FXCollections.java#L660), JavaFX 15.*</sup>

As you can see, the elements are extracted out into an array, the *array* is shuffled, and then the elements in the list are *replaced* with the array. That results in a single "replacement change" being fired.

Comment: just a note: all implementations of static modification methods in FXCollections go for the coarse-grained setAll - probably deemed to not be worth any effort for a more fine-grained notification. Which is not too difficult to implement ourselves if _really_ needed (after a close look into internal api). As always, the _really_ needs a really good reason :)

Comment: You've made the same error in your listener.  Those should not be else-if's.

Comment: @swpalmer No, I did not. The reason mine works is because I check for `wasReplaced()` before checking either `wasRemoved()` or `wasAdded()` (implicitly).

Comment: @Slaw Sorry, you are correct.  I was thinking it possible that other options were not mutually exclusive, but they appear to be.  As long as you check Replaced,Removed,Added in that order all is well. My applogies.

Answer (score 1):

I added one line to your ListChangeListener in the while loop:

```
            System.out.println("change: "+change);
```

The output I get is:

```
change: { [1, 2, 3, 4] replaced by [4, 2, 3, 1] at 0 }
wasRemoved
```

That hints at your mistake.  The verb used in the string representation is "replaced".
Getting rid of the 'else's in your listener and adding a check for wasReplaced() you will see that is exactly what you get.